# QGIS: Select polygons that are touching another polygon on all it's sides (not contain but engulfed?)

Tags: qgis, select-by-location, vector-layer, select-by-expression

Given this polygon:

[image]

I'm trying to select the inner one, but can't find a simple way using either **selection by location** or **selection by expression**

Any idea?

Comment: yep same layer, and nope I don't have postgis setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Select by expression with this expression and change the size of the buffer (end of line 2 - here: 0.0001) depending on the size of your polygons/the CRS you use (in most cases, it should work without adaptions).

Explanation: the expression evaluates if the outer boundary of a buffer around a polygon feature is within the nearest neighboring polygon.

```
within (
    boundary (buffer( $geometry,0.0001)),
    array_first (overlay_nearest (@layer, $geometry))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, once again! you're a champ. The buffer distance shouldn't too much of an issue in my case, as my polygon sizes shouldn't be varying too widely. A minor issue, that doesn't matter in my case but it could for some as this solution would also select polygons that are contain within another polygon. Anyway Thanks again.